# How to Respond in Express with a JPG Data String?

Tags: express, axios, jpeg

```js
router.get("/photos", function(req, res) {
    // Get the image
    var image_request = await axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQzUc.jpg"
    });

    console.log("Sending image");
    console.log(image_request.headers);

    res.set('Content-Type', image_request.headers["content-type"]);
    res.set('Content-Length', image_request.data.length);
    res.send(image_request.data);
}
```

There's a problem with how I'm formatting the Get response. First, I tried excluding both `res.set(...)`, but that ended up with Postman receiving image_request.data as a string with `Content-Type="text/html; charset=utf-8"`

With both `res.set(...)`, on Postman, I am getting `Content-Type="image/jpeg; charset=utf-8"`, but the image's format seems to be wrong.
[image: Postman Response Body]

What's the problem with what I'm trying to send as the response? And is there a better alternative to what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the response type of the axios request to `arraybuffer`:

```
  var image_request = await axios({
    method: "get",
    responseType: "arraybuffer", // right here
    url: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQzUc.jpg"
  });
```

Ref: [axios-config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)